# Image names are not changing in textview as images change in ImageView

Tags: android, image, textview

I have 10 images in drawable. In xml a textview, an imageview and 2 buttons to change images. Images change as next and back button clicked. But it shows only one name in textview and names not changes as images changed. Plz give me a solution. Here is Main Activity.

```
  public class Main extends Activity { 
    private ImageView hImageViewPic; 
    private Button iButton, gButton; 
    private int currentImage = 0; 
  int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 };
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 
      hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic); 
      iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
      gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev); 

     //Just set one Click listener for the image 

     iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener); 
     gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);
  } 
     View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {

     //Increase Counter to move to next Image 

       currentImage++;
       currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
       hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]); 
   }
      };
     View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
      //Increase Counter to move to next Image
         currentImage--; 
         currentImage = currentImage % images.length; 
         hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

        // I am using this to set image names in TextView 

        myPicText=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.idTextView);
        myPicText.findViewById (R.drawable.a1);
    } 
       };
     }
```

Please guide me what I have to do to change the image names as images change in imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to make a parallel String[]:

```
String[] captions = { "Text for image1", "Text for image2",....};
```

Then in your listeners do:

```
myPicText.setText(captions[currentImage]);
```